# Angular $broadcast called inside ng-repeat fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, broadcast

I have nested forms in an ng-repeat with a button whose click event calls a function that does a couple of things including a $scope.$broadcast. Everything in the function triggers once except for the broadcast which triggers on per item in the ng-repeat.

I cannot move the button outside the repeat or I lose the form and data references. I have a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Br4kGtIXidfMm4K7zN0a?p=preview) that shows the basic setup. If you enter values into one of the inputs and click next while monitoring the console and you should see the broadcast fire multiple times (once per ng-repeat item). What I need is a way to have the broadcast only fire once while still maintaining the reference to the form for validation checking as per the demo code.

Here is the JS and the rest is in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Br4kGtIXidfMm4K7zN0a?p=preview):

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('App', []),
  /** manually triggers $validate event to validate the given form */
isFormValid = function ($scope, ngForm) {
  var i = null;
  //$scope.$emit('$validate');
  $scope.$broadcast('$validate');

  if(! ngForm.$invalid) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // make the form fields '$dirty' so that the validation messages would be shown
    ngForm.$dirty = true;

    for(i in ngForm) {
      if(ngForm[i] && ngForm[i].hasOwnProperty && ngForm[i].hasOwnProperty('$dirty')) { // TODO: is 'field.$invalid' test required?
        ngForm[i].$dirty = true;
      }
    }
  }
};

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    $scope.wizardStep = 1;
    $scope.nextStep = function () {
      var ngForm = $scope['stepForm_' + $scope.wizardStep];
      if(isFormValid($scope, ngForm)) { // trigger manual validation
        $scope.wizardStep++;
      }
    };
    $scope.prevStep = function () {
      $scope.wizardStep--;
    };
    $scope.submit = function () {
      var ngForm = $scope['stepForm_' + $scope.wizardStep]; // we can make this line common
      if(isFormValid($scope, ngForm)) {
        alert('Form is valid. Submitting...');
      }
    };

  }]);
})();
```

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated and I know things like styles in the html and other aspects of the demo code are no-no's. I just did those to get the plunkr up faster.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The event is fired only once. The problem is that the testCtrl is beeing used 3 times so it's catching the event 3 times.

You need to create separate controllers for each step. A hack could be debouncing the $on handler if you really must, but I would just create separate controllers with the logic in a common service. Or maybe a base controller and child controllers (inheritance between them)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/25zIysk9OisARjdtWkSs?p=preview)

You are instantiating the controller repeatedly in each template.  You just need to instantiate it one time by wrapping your form with a div that has the ng-controller directive:

```
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <form name="wizardForm" novalidate="">
        <div ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-init="stepForm ='stepForm' + ($index + 1)">
          <ng-form name="{{stepForm}}" ng-show="currentStep == $index + 1">
            <div ng-include="step.partial"></div>
            <div class="form-group wiz-btns">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <button ng-show="currentStep > 1" type="button" class="btn btn-green" ng-click="prevStep()">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span>


                Previous
              </button>
                <button ng-show="currentStep < steps.length" type="button" class="btn btn-green" ng-click="nextStep(wizardForm[stepForm])">
                Next                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- TODO: final submit buton -->
                <!--<button></button>-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-form>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Remove the directive from the partials, so you have just this:

```
<label class="wiz-label" for="title">Step1 Input:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="step1" ng-model="data.step1" required/>
<span ng-show="stepForm1.$dirty && stepForm1.step1.$invalid" style="background:red;">Input required</span >
```

Comment: OK that makes sense, but the "partials" are actually coming from ui router state definitions so the <div ng-include="step.partial"></div> in index is actually a <div ui-view></div> and the controller name comes from the state. I didn't put all that in the plunkr to keep it simple. So while your answer works, I need to figure out how to account for it when each ng-repeat is a seperate state.

Comment: just remove the controller assignment from your states in your config and assign the controller like I have done.  Your states will load within the context of `testCtrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses that put me on the right track. The whole idea of using the states is so that the controller comes from there, so putting it in the html would not meet the real need.

However based on the prior responses, the resolution was actually a DUH moment for me. All I had to do was change this line in index.html:

```
<ng-form name="{{stepForm}}" ng-show="currentStep == $index + 1">
```

To:

```
<ng-form name="{{stepForm}}" ng-if="currentStep == $index + 1">
```

Changing this from ***ng-show*** to ***ng-if*** only puts the child form and state (controller) in once instead of once each step. This works in both the pluntr and my rela app using states. Thanks for leading me to this!